# how can I get table name from using a textbox

Tags: c#, sql

Is it possible to make a `select` query using a textbox as a reference.

Some like:

```
SELECT modeltype FROM txt_model.text
```

The value display in the textbox is the name of the table.

Comment: Yes this is possible.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: string concatenation can do this.  `var sql = "select modeltype from " + txt_model.Text`.  Be careful of sql injection however.

Comment: @paqogomez makes a good point.  I'm not sure if it's possible to prevent sql injection if you do something like this.

Comment: There are ways to manually escape sql characters to prevent injection

Comment: Yes, you can do so. Should you? Only if you care absolutely nothing about your data at all. Can you edit to explain **why** you would need to do something so careless? Is the next question you ask going to be "How do I recover all of the data that disappeared because someone deleted it all by typing something in a text box that I blindly executed?"

Comment: Also, is "modeltype" a column in every table of your database?

Comment: Thank you for responses.. I tried It and it worked...

Comment: Yes there is a modeltype on every table. I will be using a combobox instead of a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as described, but it is a bad idea.  I suggest code like the following -- it is safe and has the same UI:

```
                          // add your table names to the list below
List<string> validTables = New List<string>() {"users", "addr", "events" }; 

if (validTables.IndexOf(txt_model.text.ToLower()) > 0)
{
     // use "SELECT modeltype FROM "+txt_model.text to perform work
}
else
{
     // error code
}
```

It might be that you want a dynamic list of validTables.  In that case you could take the result of (with SQL Server as an example):

```
SELELCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

And put it in the validTables list.

Or you could just put the result of that select in a drop down.

Comment: You could also `quotename(txt_model.Text)` and make sure there are not brackets in the model name.

Answer (score 0):

One way to build your query string:

```
string sql = string.Format("Select modeltype From {0}", txt_model.Text);
// ...
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
```